# Saving User details in UserDetail Table using One-To-One Relation Django Rest API

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am new to django.
I am trying to save User details in another table using One-To-One relation by following Django document but is giving me an error

> Models.py

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=200,default="")
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects=models.Manager()
    def __str__(self):
         return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
         UserDetails.objects.create(user=instance,phone="",address="")
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userdetails.save()
```

> Serializer.py

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserDetails
        fields= ['phone','address']
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user=UserDetailsSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model =User
        fields=['id','url','username','email','password','user']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data=validated_data.pop('user')
        user=User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        UserDetails.objects.create(user=user,**user_data)          
    return user
```

When i write above in serializer.py `user=UserDetailsSerializer(read_only=True)` else give me following error

*Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `CreateUserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'user'.*

I found one way to make it work but I have to define every field manually but I want the above serializer to work

> Working Serializer.py

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    last_login=serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    date_joined=serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    phone=serializers.CharField(source='userdetails.phone')
    address=serializers.CharField(source='userdetails.address')
    updated=serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='userdetails.updated')
    # password=serializers.CharField(style={'input_type':'password'},write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=['id','first_name','last_name','username','password','phone','address','url','email','is_superuser','is_staff','last_login','date_joined','updated']
    extra_kwargs={
        'password':{'write_only':True},
    }

def create(self, validated_data):
    userdetails_data=validated_data.pop('userdetails')
    user=User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
    user.userdetails.phone=userdetails_data.get('phone')
    user.userdetails.address=userdetails_data.get('address')
    user.save()
    return user
```

Edit1: As suggested by [bdbd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6759844/bdbd) in comments I replaced `user` with `userdetails` in `CreateUserSeriailzer` it solved *Attribute Error* but was giving an error while creating user:

*(1062, "Duplicate entry '106' for key 'apis_userdetails.user_id'")*

So I replaced `UserDetails.objects.create(user=user,**user_data)`
with `user.userdetails.phone=user_data.get('phone') user.userdetails.address=user_data.get('address')`

If anyone knows how can I minimize this code further please let me know because I need to create a lot of columns in UserDetails Table so I don't want to add each value in each column manually

> Updated Serializer.py (1st One)

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #user=UserDetailsSerializer()
    userdetails=UserDetailsSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model =User
        fields=['id','url','username','email','password','userdetails']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data=validated_data.pop('userdetails')
        user=User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        # UserDetails.objects.create(user=user,**user_data)
        user.userdetails.phone=user_data.get('phone')
        user.userdetails.address=user_data.get('address')
        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: In your first serializer implementation, change `user=UserDetailsSerializer()` to `userdetails = UserDetailsSerializer()` or whatever the related name `UserDetails` has from `User`

Comment: No worries! Glad to hear it worked

Comment: @bdbd I updated the post if you know how can I minimize it further please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:
If you choose not to use signals:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    userdetails_data = validated_data.pop('userdetails')
    user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
    UserDetails.objects.create(user=user, **userdetails_data)
    return user
```

If you choose to use signals:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user_data = validated_data.pop('userdetails')
    user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
    user.userdetails.phone = user_data.get('phone')
    user.userdetails.address = user_data.get('address')
    user.userdetails.save()
    return user
```

Comment: Already tried it, giving me same error - (1062, "Duplicate entry '114' for key 'apis_userdetails.user_id'"). See my models signal maybe problem is in that?

Comment: Yes most probably. Are you creating `UserDetails` in some signal?

Comment: I added an answer that should support signals. Just choose which one you need.